# UIView with dynamic height multiple UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm making a custom UIView with 2 UILabel in it, with each UILabel having dynamic height.
I'm unable to set constraints for dynamic height. (I'm new to Auto-Layout & iOS stuff).

Both UILabels are connected to each other from Top & Bottom, and are Horizontally aligned to superview. And when I change content of one of the UILabel, UIView and UILabel does not resize as required.

Please suggest. Attaching screenshots for current constraints.

[image]

Comment: what are your constraints for the UIView?

Comment: Horizontally center aligned, Vertical center aligned & width

Comment: seems to be right. Can you send your xib file?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I made a **demo** for you according to your requirement. Download it from below link,

[Autoresize UIView and UILabel](https://github.com/badalpub1991/AutolayoutForUILabel)

**Step by Step Guide :-**

**Step 1 :-** Set constrain to UIView

1) Leading 2) Top 3) Trailing (From mainview)

[image]

**Step 2 :-** Set constrain to Label 1

1) Leading 2) Top 3) Trailing (From it's superview)

[image]

**Step 3 :-** Set constrain to Label 2

1) Leading 2) Top 3) Trailing (From it's superview)

[image]

**Step 4 :-** **Most tricky** give bottom to UILabel from UIView.

**In Xcode 10 and above - Select your UIView and Label after that from the Align Constraint section select Bottom Edges constraint.**

[image]

[image]

**Step 5 :-** (Optional) Set constrain to UIButton

1) Leading 2) Bottom 3) Trailing 4) Fixed Height (From mainview)

[image]

**Output :-**

[image]

**Note :-** Make sure you have set Number of lines =0 in Label property.

[image]

**Edit1 :-** If you want to increase size with BottomConstrain (>=) please check below Image.

[image]

I hope this info enough to understand Autoresize UIView according to UILabel's height and Autoresize UILabel According to text.

Comment: Thanks you. @RahulShirphule

Comment: What if the labels are horizontal (side by side) not vertical? And height of any label can increase. How we can tell the UIView to increase height according to this increasing label?

Comment: Best answer and easy to understand!

Comment: Best answer I ever saw on Stack Overflow

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't really work if the UIView is defined in a separate XIB. And also, if he data coming into the labels are from an API.

Comment: Well this answer surely works if you dont have given bottom constraint to outer view from its parent. Then, you'll see you constraints are ambiguous. Consider a use case where these dynamic labels are inside a self sizing cell, then you need to give bottom constraint to container. Also if there are more than two dynamic labels vertically then how will you remove ambiguity being all dynamic? I know you can solve this with stack views. But stack views are autolayout too right?

Comment: If you gave bottom constrain then you can surely Solve it with giving condition to bottom constrain like > or < its depend on your max viewsize which you want to give .

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the Lines property of both labels to 0 in interface builder.
2. Make sure there is no constraint for height of any of the labels or the uiview.
3. Make sure there are no constraints on uiview which force it to a certain size, for example, if you have a constraint on uiview for certain distance from top of superview and another constraint of certain distance from bottom of superview, it will not work.
4. Try changing the text of labels in code and height should automatically adjust.

Comment: No height constraint is added anywhere, height is still not adjusting

Comment: try uilabel.sizetofit() after changing label text.